# Getting Exception while imap idle adapter is listening on mail inbox

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

In my project i am using the imap idle channel adapter with following configuration:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow imapAdapter(MailNotifierProperties properties, SubscribableChannel errorChannel,
                                       SubscribableChannel incomingMailChannel) {
    return from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(properties.getImapUrl())
            .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                    .put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true")
                    .put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*"))
            .errorChannel(errorChannel)
            .shouldDeleteMessages(properties.getDeleteMessages()))
            .channel(incomingMailChannel)
            .get();
}
```

The configuration works fine most of the time. But one or two times a day i receive the following exception and the application is not able to process mails for about 30 minutes:

```
2018-11-18 07:05:45.342  WARN 19778 --- [TaskScheduler19] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : error occurred in idle task

javax.mail.MessagingException: * NO Mailbox is locked, will abort in 268 seconds
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3201) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3043) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:2995) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:175) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:271) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:241) [spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: * NO Mailbox is locked, will abort in 268 seconds
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:396) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.processIdleResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:3225) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3173) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        ... 14 common frames omitted

2018-11-18 07:05:45.343  WARN 19778 --- [TaskScheduler19] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:290) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:241) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: * NO Mailbox is locked, will abort in 268 seconds
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3201) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3043) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:2995) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:175) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:271) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: * NO Mailbox is locked, will abort in 268 seconds
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:396) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.processIdleResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:3225) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3173) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        ... 14 common frames omitted

2018-11-18 07:36:51.824  WARN 19778 --- [TaskScheduler19] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : error occurred in idle task

javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE Disconnected for inactivity.
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.throwClosedException(IMAPFolder.java:3601) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3737) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.exists(IMAPFolder.java:583) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:299) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:158) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:271) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:241) [spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2018-11-18 07:36:51.824  WARN 19778 --- [TaskScheduler19] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:290) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:241) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE Disconnected for inactivity.
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.throwClosedException(IMAPFolder.java:3601) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3737) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.exists(IMAPFolder.java:583) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:299) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:158) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:271) ~[spring-integration-mail-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-11-18 07:37:01.872  INFO 19778 --- [TaskScheduler19] o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
```

Right now i have no answers for the following questions
1) What causes the error message: "* NO Mailbox is locked, will abort in 268 seconds"?
2) Why there are no mails processed within the next 30 minutes?

**Update:**
i have checked the log files on the server, and i could find the following message that occurs at the same time:

```
Nov  18 07:05:33 MailServer postfix/local[19960]: 5D5AAC20FA: to=<sender@domain.com>, orig_to=<recipient@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=19, delays=0.01/0/0/19, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (cannot update mailbox /var/mail/mailUser for user mailUser. unable to lock for exclusive access: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

However, the file that locks the mailbox is removed after 30 seconds.

Is there a way to configure the imap channel adapter to reconnect in a shorter period. I still have the problem, that the application waits 30 minutes to reconnect to the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

The message is coming from your mail server so you need to ask the owner of your mail server, or if it's your own mail server you need to look into the log files to see why it's complaining about the mailbox being locked.  Perhaps two applications are trying to access the same mailbox and the mail server isn't able to handle more than one application accessing the mailbox at a time?

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question. The mailbox is locked and so the application fails to request mails.

Comment: The code that gets the MessagingException will need to disconnect and reconnect.  That may be deep inside the Spring framework code, which I don't know anything about.